# Trash characters when using buffers in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, char

I have a DLL that I need to handle in C++. I'm using WxWidgets (standard compilation, but I also tried Unicode on/off) and NetBeans. I also tried dealing with this without WxWidgets (`windows.h`) and had same problems.

Here is how I access the DLL functions using WxWidgets:

```
// -------------------- POINTERS TO FUNCTIONS
typedef bool(*TYPE_DLL_SetLicense)(char*, char*);
typedef bool(*TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*); 
typedef char*(*TYPE_DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION)(void);

class DLL_Library
{
public:
    // pointers to functions inside dll
    TYPE_DLL_SetLicense DLL_SetLicense;        //initialize - will wor fine as it returns only true/false (buffer only provide data)
    TYPE_DLL_PingConnection DLL_PingConnection;      //ping to serwer. Will return trahs, becouse it uses buffer to provide data ang get answear back
    TYPE_DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION;      //error description. No buffer, no trouble. Returns correct string.
    wxDynamicLibrary dynLib2;

    int initialize(void)
    {
        //patch to dll
        wxString path = wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath().BeforeLast('\\') + _("\\DLL_dll\\DLLMOK.dll");
        if(!wxFile::Exists(path)) return -1;

        //load dll
        if(!dynLib2.Load(path)) return -2;

        //Assign functions in dll to variable
        DLL_SetLicense=(TYPE_DLL_SetLicense) dynLib2.GetSymbol(wxT("DLL_SetLicense"));
        DLL_PingConnection=(TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)  dynLib2.GetSymbol(wxT("DLL_PingConnection"));
        DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION=(TYPE_DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION) dynLib2.GetSymbol(wxT("DLL_ERROR_DESCRIPTION"));


    return 0;
   }
};
```

And here is the function I run. It should return and XML content, that I try to save to the file.

```
//DLL_PingConnection            
//result ping to be save in file
wxFile file_ping_xml;
plik_ping_xml.Open(wxT("C:\\dll\\ping.xml"),wxFile::write);
char buffor_ping_xml[2000];

//I run the function here
bool is_ping = DLL_PingConnection(buffor_ping_xml);

if(is_ping)
{

    tex_box->AppendText(wxT("DLL_PingConnection True\n"));

    //we save result to file
    bool is_write_ping_ok = file_ping_xml.Write(buffor_ping_xml,2000);
    if (is_write_ping_ok){tex_box->AppendText(wxT("Save to file is ok ok\n"));}
    else {tex_box->AppendText(wxT("Save to file failed :( \n"));}                
}
else
{
    tex_box->AppendText(wxT("DLL_PingConnection False\n"));
} 


std::cout << "Error description: " << DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION() << "\n"; //will work fine both in saving to file, and in streaming to screen.
```

The problem is that inside the file instead of good content I get rubbish like this:

[image]

NOTE that this only happens in functions that use buffers like:

```
char buffer[2000] //buffer will contain for example file xml
function do_sth_with_xml(buffer) //buffer containing xml will (should) be overwriten with xml results of the function - in our case DLL_PingCONNECTION should save in buffer xml with connection data
```

Documentation say that the DLL operates on Windows-1250. File `ping.xml` I have set to windows ANSI, but I don't think problem lies here.

**EDIT**: I have written problem without WxWidgets (I load DLL using `windows.h`) - same problems. Here is the code: [Getting trash data in char* while using it as buffer in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035286/getting-trash-data-in-char-while-using-it-as-buffer-in-function) . Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answear: [Getting trash data in char* while using it as buffer in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035286/getting-trash-data-in-char-while-using-it-as-buffer-in-function).

Thanks everyone - expecially for patience.

Answer (score 0):

You named a function

```
DLL_PingConnection=(TYPE_DLL_PingConnection) dynLib2.GetSymbol(....
```

and call it with

```
OSOZ.OSOZ_PingConnection(buffor_ping_xml);
```

you typedef a function

```
typedef bool(*TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*);
```

you create a variable

```
char buffor_ping_xml[2000];
```

in your typedef it is `char*` and your buffor_ping_xml is `char`

how can that work ?

try

```
char *buffor_ping_xml = new char[2000]; 
/* or */
wchar_t *buffor_ping_xml = new wchar_t[2000];
/* or */
wxChar *buffor_ping_xml = new wxchar[2000];

bool is_ping = DLL_PingConnection(buffor_ping_xml);
wxString mystring = wxString::FromUTF8(buffor_ping_xml);
```

write `mystring` to file.

**To Do:**

- look in your `wxwidgets\libs` folder for your `libs` 
  are there `libwxmsw29ud_*` with a **'u'** in the name (after version number here 29)?
  If not **You can not use unicode**

If yes next steps

- for all different test `char *`, `wchar_t *`, `wxChar *` give the files different name.
  for example file_ping_xml.Open(wxT("C:\dll\ping_w_t_FromUTF8.xml"), ...
  for wchar_t * in combination with
  `wxString mystring = wxString::FromUTF8(buffor_ping_xml);`
- also in combination with
- `wxString mystring(buffor_ping_xml);`
- Then check out the look like, of the files in a browser .

To test you can go to your wxWidgets sample folder . Compile in the folder `C:\wxWidgets\samples\docview\docview.cpp` . Open with docview.exe a unicode file . How does it look.

[Unicode download file](http://moskito-x.de/stack/unicodeMemo.zip)

**Unicode-related compilation settings**

You should define `wxUSE_UNICODE` to 1 to compile your program in Unicode mode. This currently works for wxMSW, wxGTK, wxMac and wxX11. If you compile your program in ANSI mode you can still define `wxUSE_WCHAR_T` to get some limited support for wchar_t type.

Comment: Hi. The function name was a typo(now fixed) - I striped the code of some things to make it easer to read. However concerning variable `buffor_ping_xml[2000]` this is the only way it works if I give bufor like this: `char * buffor_ping_xml` program will crash. In documentation I have a data type `PChar` to be used. Any ideas?

Comment: Also: taking away * from typdef will not compile.

Comment: @baron_bartek : Have you tried it with : `const char *buffor_ping_xml = new char[2000];`

Comment: Thx for idea. I changed typedef to `typedef bool(*TYP_OSOZ_PingConnection)(const char*);`  and used `const char *buffor_ping_xml = new char[2000];` It compiled, but still I get trash. Also are you sure that functions will be able to alter const char? Sorry I'm totaly new in c++

Comment: `char *buffor_ping_xml = new char[2000];`  - same result as before. `wchar_t *buffor_ping_xml = new wchar_t[2000]` - result is different but still makes no sense. example:  0x4afaa50

Comment: Yes. I was just working on it :). Unfortunatelly is creates the same result. Only wchar_t in anyhow different. Let me just tell you that functions in this dll that doesnt use buffers work just fine - I will edit my question and add example.

Comment: Thanx for your support, but I have already tried to compile WxWidgets with UNICODE=0 (c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make - f makefile.gcc MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=1 UNICODE=0 BUILD=release). Result was the same. This seems not to be WxWidgets problem - I have written similar aplication without WxWidgets at all to handle dll. I will post code in different question. I belive this is rather a problem of buffers usage (or lack of ability to use) then the any loading library itself.

Comment: @baron_bartek : If you want unicode then compile it with UNICODE=1 !!! Have you opened the files in a browser ? Can you give us the name of your `libwxmsw29ud_core.a` ?

Comment: @baron_bartek : look also at my updated answer. And edit your question ! The line : `dynLib2.GetSymbol(wxT("DLL_PingConnection"));` hangs between code formatting.

Comment: I tried both with UNICODE=1 and 0, also with MONOLITHIC 1 or 0. But result were always the same.

Comment: @baron_bartek : Can not you or do not you want ? I Can not see any libs name in your comment. I think you don't understand . you must compile complete wxwidgets not just your file. Also no comment : have you compiled and run `docview.cpp` . Have you test your output file in a browser ? all my question no comment why ? btw rename ping.xml to ping.txt to test in a browser. Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: moskito-x : I apriciate your contributions. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035286/getting-trahs-data-in-char-while-using-it-as-buffer-in-function . I put that question there to present code without WxWidgets at all. I used windows.h but still I get absolutelly same problems, so basicly speaking it's not WxWidgets fault as I suspected before.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. Arrays decay to pointers. That's part of the language. So the definition of buffor_ping_xml is compatible with char* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
DLL_PingConnection=(TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)
```

shouldn't it be

```
DLL_PingConnection=(TYPE_DLL_PingConnection) dynLib2.GetSymbol(wxT("DLL_PingConnection"));
```

?

seems otherwise you will not get a valid pointer to the function in the DLL.

as a general rule you should check return values, especially from a DLL
you load dynamically since it happens that you sometimes get another version 
of the DLL which may have a function with same name but other signature or 
where is missing entirely.

Comment: My bad. I edited my question. PS: I do check the return values of dll functions. I get succec (bool -> true) but in the buffer I find only trash, while functions that return string instead of bool (don't use buffer) work just fine. Example is the DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION