# Getting trash data in char* while using it as buffer in function

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi, dll, char

I'm loading a delphi dll in c++. When I use functions with char* as buffers (char* given as parameter to the procedure) I get only trash data. 
When I have functions that return char* all is fine.

I'm new to c++ and I spend a lot of time trying to crack this. Please help.

Everything is explained in code below. I have put there 3 functions to show exacly what I mean.

Example function that has problem with buffer is: 
DLL_PingConnection(var avXml:PChar):Boolean; - it returns true/false, as parameter it takes buffer and the function is done in buffer there should be valid xml (but there is only trash)

```
#include <windows.h> //this will load delphi dll
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

// ------------------------------------------------ pointers on functions inside Delphi DLL (32 bits)
typedef bool(*TYPE_DLL_SetLicense)(char*, char*); //initialize dll stuff - I load licence from a file into char* - everything works fine
typedef bool(*TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*); //the char* is buffer - I give empty char* as parameter and I should get correct xml with serwer data - I GET ONLY TRASH :(
typedef char*(*TYPE_DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION)(void); //this function does not use buffer it returns char* - everything works fine

//so as you see problem is with buffers and function like this: DLL_PingConnection(buffer)

int main()
{

// ------------------------------------------------ Loading the library  
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\full_path\\SOMEDLL.dll");

    //checking the library
    if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {std::cout << "Could NOT load the dynamic library" << std::endl;return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    else{std::cout << "dynamic library loaded" << std::endl;}

// ------------------------------------------------ START: resolving functions adresses

    TYPE_DLL_SetLicense DLL_SetLicense = (TYPE_DLL_SetLicense)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "DLL_SetLicense");
    if (!DLL_SetLicense) {std::cout << "Could NOT locate the function: DLL_SetLicense" << std::endl;return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    else{std::cout << "Function DLL_SetLicense located" << std::endl;}

    TYPE_DLL_PingConnection DLL_PingConnection = (TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "DLL_PingConnection");
    if (!DLL_PingConnection) {std::cout << "Could NOT locate the function: DLL_PingConnection" << std::endl;return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    else{std::cout << "Function DLL_PingConnection located" << std::endl;}

    TYPE_DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION = (TYPE_DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION");
    if (!DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION) {std::cout << "Could NOT locate the function: DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION" << std::endl;return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    else{std::cout << "Function DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION located" << std::endl;}        


std::cout << "\n\nInitialization over. \n\n" << std::endl;  


// ------------------------------------------------ START: calling functions from delphi dll       

//DLL_SetLicence - this function take buffer as parameter, but dont return anything into the buffer. All works fine.

    //start - we read licence from file
    char buffer_licence[1242];
    memset(buffer_licence,0,sizeof(buffer_licence));

//I read content of buffer_licence usinf ifstream from the file here (but I don't put the code, to keep sample minimal)

    //we set licence with dll function
    bool is_licence = DLL_SetLicense(buffer_licence,(char*)"");

    //the output
    if (is_licence == TRUE)
      std::cout << "Licence has been set\n";
    else
      std::cout << "Licence has been NOT set\n";




//DLL_PingConnection - it takes empty buffer as parameter, it should save xml into buffer but it saves only trash.

    //we try to save ping to the file - buffer
    char buffor_ping_xml[2000];
    memset(buffor_ping_xml,0,sizeof(buffor_ping_xml));

    //this should gieve proper xml, but it returns only trash.... please help
    bool is_ping = DLL_PingConnection(buffor_ping_xml);

    if(is_ping)
    {

        std::cout << "DLL_PingConnection True\n"; //function returned true, so it worked correct.

        std::cout << buffor_ping_xml; //but in the buffer is trash that I show on the screen. I also tried to put buffor_ping_xml info the file (diferent ways) but always result was trash just like on screen.

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "DLL_PingConnection False: \n";
    }           



//DLL_ERR_DESCRIPTION - if will automaticly return error description if there is any error to report. No buffer, no problems.

        std::cout << buffor_ping_xml; //the data on screet is fine, so is in file and everywhere else.



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

PingConnection function will return only this instead of good xml.

[image]

EDIT:

Oroginally I used Netbeans + MinGW, but as suggested in comments I have used alternative compilers: Borland builder c++ 6.0, and Embarcadero RAD Studio XE3 (C++ Builder). The problems stayed the same even thou I used all calling convention types Remy Lebeau mentioned.

```
typedef bool(*TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*); //standard calling convention default for compiler - returns trash
typedef bool(__cdecl *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*); //returns trash also
typedef bool(__stdcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*); //doesnt write anything to the buffer
typedef bool(__fastcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*); //returns trash
```

I have encountered small problem under c++ builder. I can't clean buffer under this enviroment:

```
memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer)); // will crash the program under c++ builder
```

Trying to use 'char *&' will crash the program also.

```
typedef bool(__cdecl *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&);
OR
typedef bool(__stdcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&);
OR
typedef bool(__fastcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&);

char * buffer;
bool is_ping = DLL_PingConnection(buffer);
```

Using char ** will cause type mismatch with buffer.

EDIT2:

As requested by David Heffernan I attach sample of documentation. Important parts are trasnated to english. Rest is just structure of xlm that PIngConnection should return. Not much of help there - entire documentation is like this.

[image]

PS: I asked similar question here: [Trash characters when using buffers in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945003/trash-characters-when-using-buffers-in-c) - code based on WxWidgets (I though WxWidgets creates the problem, but it doesn't. Maybe someone will find WxWidgets code usefull thou).

EDIT 3:

I managed to get some more information about dll.

Delphi version is 7.

For sure calling type is stdcall. ( DLL_PingConnection: function(var avXml: PChar): Boolean; stdcall; )

This is how a function from this dll is called in delphi:

```
lPointer := nil;  //pointer
lOSOZPointer := nil; //pointer
lpXML := nil; //pChar

lpXML:=StringToPChar(lXML);
lPointer := lpXML;

lWynik:=OSOZ_GetServerDataTime(lpXML);
if lWynik then
begin
  lOSOZPointer := lpXML;
  //akcja na wyniku
end;

if lPointer <> nil then begin
  Freemem(lPointer);
end;
if lOSOZPointer <> nil then begin
  OSOZ_FreeMem(lOSOZPointer);
end;
```

---

Comment: Can you log the returned data as hex and add it to your question?

Comment: Does `DLL_PingConnection` return an allocated buffer?  Typically, functions that write into a caller-provided buffer also take a buffer size parameter.

Comment: Eric Brown: There is no size parameter. There is only 1 parameter: var avXml: PChar and reslt: boolean. Function returns true, but inside buffer I only get thigns that make no sense.

Comment: simonc: can you tell me what you need exacly and how to do it? Sorry this I'm new in c++.

Comment: are you sure that that's the purpose of the function, to write to the buffer? cuz I have a hunch that it's not

Comment: losif M. There are many function like this in this dll, PingConnection is accually the easiest and they all state like this (from documentation) : var avXml: PChar - function input data while calling function, result of the function while leaving function (in PingConnection case buffer is to be empty, but it should contain xml whe function is done. Other functions require input xml inside the buffer)

Comment: @baron_bartek : Edit your question to point to the delphi part DLL_PingConnection(var yvXml:PChar):Boolean; Add `delphi` Tag to the question. You will get more help.

Comment: 1. There should be less code. You should cut this down to a minimal sample. 2. If this is an interface problem we need to see both sides of the interface. You have not presented the Delphi side. For example, it would surprise me if the Delphi DLL used `cdecl` as the code in the question does. But you need to show the Delphi side of the interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trash characters when using buffers in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945003/trash-characters-when-using-buffers-in-c)  Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: David Heffernan: its not duplicate becouse my code is different (first question was c++ and WxWidgets code, this one is without WxWidgets to prove this is not WxWidgets problem). Unfortunatelly I dont have accdess to dephi code, I only have their dll + documentatiopn, unleass this is possible to decompile this dll or do anything else with it that could help to solve the problem. If it is cdecl what I can do about it?

Comment: You've got documentation?! Can't we see it too? It's not fair if we can't. And sure it's a dupe. Who cares whether there's any wxWidgets? The issue is at the interface boundary and that's identical. I urge you to remove lots of code here and show a minimal sample. And show docs for the other side of the interface.

Comment: Documentation is not in english :P. I translated what is neccessary, but if you need more, then I will translate more. Like I said I'm new in c++ so I thought that maybe WxWidgets is a problem as I used it to load dll - so I wrote program based on windows.h - totaly same problems :/. This Dll is really my first program in c++ so it's totaly over my head :P. What code I should remove? I show 3 functiopns as valid examples. Should I remove for example the code that saves results to the file? (I thought that it is important to show that the problem exist when I put result on screen/file).

Comment: I don't see how we can help you if you can't tell us what's on the other side of the interface.

Comment: I have dll and 100 pages of documentation in polish. Tell me what you need and I will translate it to english :) There is really not much interesting stuff in documentation. Basicly it says: run this function to get this, the run this to get this.... and so on. This is why I chose setLicence functiom, getErrorDescription, and PingConnection - they require really nothing to be run, so there is no possibility it's a misusage of functionflow inside dll (you just run them whenever you want and get result like current ping connection with serwer).

Comment: David I really apricitate help - please tell me what you need exacly. (really. Documentation is 99% bunch of functions described the same way as I shown in the question, and the only ones I have problem with are the ones with buffer like PingCDonnection, and I quote documentation: DLL_PingConnection(var avXml:PChar):Boolean; It takes a char* as buffer, it should save xml to buffer, and return true. It does return true, buit in buffer I get trash :/ )

Comment: I'd like to see the code that goes with the DLL. Is there a Delphi unit that wraps it up? Normally a var PChar would mean buffer allocated by DLL. But then you'd need a deallocate function. Is there one? Is there any example code that calls this function?

Comment: Code that goes with the DLL? You mean the compiled dll? (I only have it this way and no possibility to get more). There are no deallocate functions for every dll function. There are only 2 function that close dll work (close connection, clean_data). Concerning examples there aren't any in documentation, not even the xml's (there are graphs that contain all emelents of xml and possible values). Energiners that created the dll also have nothing - but there is compiled aplications that uses this dll in delphi. Maybe it would be possible to contact them and get some delphi code, if it will help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> DLL_PingConnection(var avXml:PChar):Boolean;

This is not a  **full** declaration. Obviously, it is a `function` since it has a `Boolean` return type.  But does it also declare a calling convention as well -  `stdcall` (`__stdcall` in C/C++) or `cdecl` (`__cdecl` in C/C++)?  If not, then it is using Delphi's default `register` convention instead (which is `__fastcall` in Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero C++ compilers only, but has no equivalent in any other C/C++ compiler).  Your existing typedefs are using your C++ compiler's default calling convention, which is usually `__cdecl`.  Calling convention mismatches are the most common problem with using DLLs, as it causes mismanagement of the call stack, which affects how parameters are passed, accessed, and cleaned up.

Also, what version of Delphi was the DLL written in? `PChar` is `PAnsiChar` (`char*` in C++) in Delphi 2007, but is `PWideChar` (`wchar_t*` in C++) in Delphi 2009 and later.  Chances are, since the data is XML, then `PAnsiChar`/`char*` is likely being used.

Also, the `PChar` parameter is being passed as a `var` in the Delphi declaration, which is the same as a pointer in C and a reference in C++.

You need these important pieces of information in order to use this DLL function in C/C++ code.  Unless the documentation explictly states these details, or the DLL has a C/C++ .h/.hpp file showing the actual declaration, then the best you can do is guess, and there are several variations possible given the incomplete declaration you have shown so far:

(`char*&` can be replaced with `char**` if needed):

```
typedef bool (__cdecl *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&);
```

```
typedef bool (__stdcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&);
```

```
typedef bool (__fastcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&);
```

```
typedef bool (__cdecl *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(wchar_t*&);
```

```
typedef bool (__stdcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(wchar_t*&);
```

```
typedef bool (__fastcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(wchar_t*&);
```

If the DLL functions are using `cdecl` or `stdcall`, then you are OK, as most C/C++ compilers support those calling conventions.  However, if the DLL functions are using `register` instead, and if you are not using a Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero C++ compiler, then you are SOL.  You would have to wrap the DLL inside another Delphi-written DLL that exports wrapper functions that use more portable signatures.

Comment: __fastcall is not the same as register. And there's also the issue of a PChar passed by reference. What does that mean? Should there be a deallocation function too? Or is the function just badly designed and it's still caller allocates buffer.

Comment: This is really solid info! Thx. I'm preety sure that dll uses older version of delphi, but I will confirm this information with the guys who prvide it (can take some time before they respond). Would it be possible for you to give exmple how to use char*& when calling a function? I tried but I can't make it compile (with the &) When I do compile it I will try all the possibilities you described.

Comment: The info is not that solid. If your function really is declared that way in Delphi code then you cannot call it from your C++ compiler unless you happen to be using the Emba compiler. Or are on 64 bit! That's because you can't match the Delphi `register` calling convention. Remy is simply wrong when he says that `__fastcall` is the same as `register`. As for passing `char*&`, you first of all need to work out the semantics. You need to know who is responsible for allocating the buffer. Is it your code or the DLL that does so?

Comment: What I said about `__fastcall` applies to C++Builder's flavor of `__fastcall`, not Microsoft's flavor of `__fastcall`.  C++Builder's `__fastcall` is **specifically designed** to be compatible with Delphi's `register` calling convention. Otherwise, C++Builder code could not interact with Delphi RTL/VCL libraries at all, since just about everything in the Delphi RTL/VCL uses the `register` calling convention (and this is why C++Builder compilers have a separate `__msfastcall` calling convention for Microsoft compatibility).

Comment: If the OP is using a C++ compiler other than C++Builder, then he will NOT be able to use a Delphi-written DLL if it is, in fact, using the Borland-specific `register` calling convention, versus the more portable `cdecl` or `stdcall` calling conventions.

Comment: As for using `char*&`, the original Delphi declaration is passing the `PChar` parameter as `var`, which is the same as a reference in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What you say in the comments about `__fastcall` is accurate. But you should say it in the answer. I suggest that you edit the answer so that it is accurate.

Comment: Just a shameless plug: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#cconvs .

Comment: Remy Lebeau, David Heffernan. I updated my question. Could you take a look? Thanx.

Comment: @baron_bartek: The doc snippet you showed does not describe the calling convention of the DLL function, but that is a VERY IMPORTANT detail. Also, you MUST declare the parameter as either `char**` or `char*&` in C++, as that is what `var PChar` in Delphi is actually expecting (a **reference** to a character pointer). Also, you are passing an **uninitialized** pointer to the parameter. Unless the function allocates and returns a new block of memory (which might explain why it takes the parameter as a `var` reference), then you may need to pass in an actual buffer that you allocate yourself.

Comment: @baron_bartek: And this is assuming that the DLL's use of `PChar` is `char*` and not `wchar_t*`.

Comment: @baron_bartek: The uninitialized pointer would explain your `memset()` crash. As for the compiler error when declaring the parameter as `char**`, you would have to pass the variable using the `&` address operator, eg: `char *buffer; DLL_PingConnection(&buffer);`.  You don't need to use the `&` address operator when declaring the parameter as `char*&` instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I'm nut sure if I fully understand you, but this is how I tried it (with every calling possible) `typedef bool(__fastcall *TYPE_DLL_PingConnection)(char*&); char buffor_ping_xml[2000]; char * buffor_ping_xml_pointer = &buffor_ping_xml[0]; bool is_ping = DLL_PingConnection(*&buffor_ping_xml_pointer);` I also tried with wchar_t but I think it should be char becouse PIngConnection function didn't write anything to the wchar_t buffer at all in any calling type.

Comment: And what happened? Is `DLL_PingConnection()` returning true or false? If true, is `buffer_ping_xml_pointer` being updated to point at a different memory address or not? Also, passing `*&buffer_ping_xml_pointer` is the same as passing `buffer_ping_xml_pointer` by itself: `DLL_PingConnection(buffer_ping_xml_pointer)`.

Comment: Ha. Sorry. I wrote enerything except the result. Basicly: I still get trash in the buffer on every calling type. Details: DLL_PingConnection returns true for __cdecl and __stdcall but NOT __fastcall (does it mean that deplhi dll is not using fastcall calling?). On __cdecl content of the buffer is changed (different trash), on __stdcall buffer content stays the same as initialized, on __fastcal buffer is changed but like I said function return false.

Comment: I still can't clear the buffer using memset. I tried everything. Example: `char buffor_ping_xml[2000]; char * buffor_ping_xml_pointer = &buffor_ping_xml[0]; memset(buffor_ping_xml,0,sizeof(buffor_ping_xml));` (I used buffor_ping_xml in the mem set buffor_ping_xml_pointer, with *&, & and without)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35155/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-baron-bartek)